# How to use jsdom in a file which is bundled with Browserify?

Tags: javascript, unit-testing, browserify, jsdom, node.js-tape

I am trying to create a unit test for a function. In the test, I would like to emulate the global `document` object (e.g. [`document.getElementById()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/getElementById)) using the [jsdom package](https://github.com/jsdom/jsdom).  I have installed `jsdom` in my project, and to my test file (`test.pageContent.js`) added a single line:

`const jsdom = require('jsdom')`

But from the command line, when I Browserify this file then execute it, it fails with this output:

```
>> node_modules/.bin/browserify test.pageContent.js -t [ babelify ] --outfile test-bundle.js && node test-bundle.js

Browserslist: caniuse-lite is outdated. Please run:
npx browserslist@latest --update-db
C:\Users\snarl\development\project\test-bundle.js:59075
module.exports = typeof self == 'object' ? self.FormData : window.FormData;

ReferenceError: window is not defined
```

Why is that occurring and how can I resolve it?

I am Browserifying in this manner because the function-under-test is in an ES6 module, which itself calls other ES6 modules.  If I don't Browserify and Babelify like this, errors occur. Maybe this is what needs to be investigated on my end?

---

**Of Note**

- From the command line, if I execute the test file with the Browserify command, but without any Babelify transform, the same error occurs.
- From the command line, if I execute the test file without the Browserify command at all, there is no error at all.
- I am using [Tape](https://github.com/substack/tape) as my unit test harness.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After [discussing with the jsdom devs](https://github.com/jsdom/jsdom/issues/2726#issuecomment-831656420), the answer to my question is that things are working as intended with jsdom in this case.  The two supported jsdom use cases are:

- using jsdom as a CommonJS module in Node
  or
- using jsdom in a Browserify bundle in web browsers

In my case, I'm trying to use jsdom in a Browserify bundle in Node. I will try to use it in a browser and see how I go. Initial tests look promising.